# Need help recovering Sitecore items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I accidentally deleted a node in Sitecore. I see it in the site but not in the preview.  I tried packaging it and unpackaging it to the preview but that didn't work. Other than pulling from a back-up, is there a way to get my items from the live site back to the unpublished?

Comment: Have you checked the Sitecore Recycling Bin for your items? You can find the recycling bin in the Sitecore Menu when on the Desktop. You can restore deleted items from there.

Comment: Yes.  It is not in the recycling bin.

Comment: I think I am going to try transferring it from the web database.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're saying that you have an item or items in the web (live site) database that no longer exist in the master (unpublished) database.

To move the web items to the master database, go to the web database item, right-click the item, select "Copying ...", then Transfer.  You can select the source item and then the target location.  This won't recover all the versions (if you had any), but merely the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Transfer method will work but sometimes it may fails. What I do is that I generate a package from the Web database, then convert it with the tool I have implemented. You can download it [here](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Package_Modifier.aspx) on marketplace.

It is a desktop app where you specify the Sitecore package to convert, the source and the target. It will change the metadata and path so that it gets installed on the desired database

Answer (score 0):

Hedgehog Development creates a tool called Razl. It is good for comparing databases. You can use it to compare the two databases and move the items that you need moved. Since they are the creators of TDS, it should have similar functionality.